# Effective fastening methods for attaching French cleats to OSB

Tags: walls, wood, framing-fasteners

I have metal studs 24" O.C. covered with 7/16" OSB. I want to attach French cleats to the walls, and I can land a set of screws into a stud every 2 feet, but I'd also like to put in some fasteners between the studs as well. Is there a standard method, or standard fastener type that works best for anchoring into the OSB only with no stud/framing behind it? I realize this question can result in some opinion based answers and I'm ok with that in this scenario since I plan to do some testing on scrap OSB before I get started.

[image]

[image]
This piece of 3/4" plywood is held only to the 7/16" OSB with 6 screws. I weigh 175lbs and basically did a pull up on it. I'm now confident that fastening to a metal stud every 2' and one set of screws in between I'll be able to hang just about anything I'd need to.

Comment: What are you hanging on the cleats?

Comment: If your cleats are hardwood, screws every 24" into studs will be just fine

Comment: Will just be general tool holders (screwdrivers, hammers, levels n such. Might hang 
 small power tools like palm router, sanders etc......nothing heavy like cabinets. And they'll be made from 3/4" plywood so I feel I need more attachment points than just every 2'

Comment: 3/4" plywood is good stuff, you'll be fine

Comment: If you're not likely to want to remove them, construction adhesive and 1-1/4" to 1-1/2" screws.

Comment: I think where they are going is about the only place they can be used, but just in case I'm not going to use adhesive.

Comment: Just attach to the studs, you'll be fine.  For small tools you'll be way more than fine, you don't even need the cleats, you can just use hanging hardware screwed directly to the OSB.   If you do find a way to tear the cleats out of the studs by brute force, or to tear apart the plywood by force, I don't think *anything* you add by attaching to the OSB will make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned just add more screws, but another option is threaded wood inserts made for softer wood.

https://www.ezlok.com/threaded-inserts-for-wood

They have a bit more bite so can likely hold up a bit better in OSB. I like to coat the inserts with wood glue to really lock in the fibers after drilling

Answer (score 0):

There are many designs of fixings that "butterfly" out behind and give a higher loading.

Make sure that the ones you choose will work with the thickness of the material - otherwise you will not get the support you expect.

Available in most of the big stores.

Comment: I have a fair assortment of wall anchors at my disposal, but would prefer to just fasten directly into the OSB instead of mounting an anchor and screwing into it. Since I will have screws holding the cleats to the wall every 24", my gut tells me that some additional screws straight into the OSB "should" be sufficient to help support the cleat.

Comment: I did not mention screwing an anchor to the surface… @roasthead